# jquery selector append multiple div instead of one for each

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to display link preview on each link with jquery, but actually my code append multiple divs (one for each link in the body) instead of one for the link itself.

here the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eg4zwpk9/4/

my code so far

```
this.$(".Post-body").find('a').each((i, e) => {

      this.$('.Post-body').attr('id', 'value');

      const isMobile = navigator.userAgentData.mobile;
      let controller = new AbortController();

      let href = e.getAttribute("href");
      console.log(href)

      if (isMobile === false) {
        fetch(`https://preview-api.bbspace.top/?url=` + encodeURIComponent(href), {
          method: "GET",
          mode: "cors",
          signal: controller.signal,
          credentials: "omit"
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)

            if (!e.text.startsWith("http")) return;
            let $s = $('#value a')

            let imgResp = '<img class="screenImg" src="' + response.image + '" width="250">';

            if (response.image === undefined) {
              imgResp = '<img class="screenImg" src="https://www.studioippocrate.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/pac-404.png" width="250">';
            }


            this.$('#value a').append('<div class="dropdown-prev">\n' +
              '  <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>\n' +
              '  <div class="dropdown-content-prev">\n' +
              '    <div class="donContainer">\n' +
              '   ' + imgResp + '' +
              '    <div class="titleDesc">' + response.description + '</div>  ' +
              '  </div>\n' +
              '  </div>\n' +
              '</div>');
          });
      }
    });
```

how can i display only the correct result for EACH link?

Comment: Why are you programmatically adding `id="value"` to each element? IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You append that preview element to all links that are inside #value.
Instead of this:

```
            this.$('#value a').append('<div class="dropdown-prev">\n' +
              '  <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>\n' +
              '  <div class="dropdown-content-prev">\n' +
              '    <div class="donContainer">\n' +
              '   ' + imgResp + '' +
              '    <div class="titleDesc">' + response.description + '</div>  ' +
              '  </div>\n' +
              '  </div>\n' +
              '</div>');
```

You have to do like this:

```
            $(e).append('<div class="dropdown-prev">\n' +
              '  <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>\n' +
              '  <div class="dropdown-content-prev">\n' +
              '    <div class="donContainer">\n' +
              '   ' + imgResp + '' +
              '    <div class="titleDesc">' + response.description + '</div>  ' +
              '  </div>\n' +
              '  </div>\n' +
              '</div>');
```

You have there already each function which give you link element.
Also there is no point to assign that id to .Post-body.

Comment: that works fine on a jfiddle, but unfortunately not in my forum...its really odd

Comment: @juniorDevFla what's not working on forum?

Comment: the code u provide works fine on jsfiddle, but not on my forum (this code is for a forum extension)

Answer (score 1):

I've copied your fiddle and [corrected it](https://jsfiddle.net/polypode/d03eguy1/8/)
In summary, when you select your link with `this.$('#value a')` before appending the new html, you are selecting all the links of the page, so it will add the new html to all your links.
To correct it, you can just convert your `e` into jquery like so : `$(e).append(...)`